# SQL Friendship tablestructure and querying

Tags: sql, database

SQL Problem:

**I am open for changes in my Tables. If I should add a FriendshipRequest tbl or if IsActive is enough to gather the information needed. Or if I should go with Status: Pending, Accepted, Declined and so on.**

Got table User and table Friendship.

For each user that has friends, or a friendinvitation pending, either from himself, or to himself, 2 rows is inserted.

```
| UID   | FID   | IsActive |
|  1    |  2    |    1     |
|  2    |  1    |    1     |
```

^
Here we got one friendinvitation from UID to FID.
The invitation has been accepted and they are friends.

```
| UID   | FID   | IsActive |
|  1    |  2    |    1     | 
|  2    |  1    |    0     |
```

^
Here we got one pending invitation, from UID 1 > 2 for a friendship. 
The other user(UID:2) hasnt handled the invitation. Accept/Decline aka 1/0

```
| UID   | FID   | IsActive |
|  1    |  2    |    0     | 
|  2    |  1    |    0     |
```

^
Here we got a declined request.
The user with ID 2 has declined the invitation. Wich set both columns to False / 0.

The thing is, I want to write queries for:
    Getting all pending requests. (IsActive 1 and IsActive = 0)
    Get all friends for a specific user (Active Friends IsActive = 1)

The tables I use is:
    User        Columns: UserID
    Friendship  COlumns: UserID, FriendID, IsActive

Ive tried a UNION ALL, the thing is I dont know how to handle the result.

```
SELECT 
    u.UserID, u.Username, f.IsActive
FROM Friendship f, [User] u
  WHERE f.UserID = 6 AND f.FriendID = u.UserID AND f.IsActive = 1 

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    u.UserID, u.UserName, f.IsActive
FROM Friendship f, [User] u
  WHERE f.FriendID = 6 AND f.UserID = u.UserID AND f.IsActive = 1
```

Comment: `2 columns is inserted.` did you mean two rows are inserted in said table for each friend request?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Of course its rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all pending requests you can join the table to itself, checking for only one of them to be active.  This setup assumes that IsActive is a `BIT`, if you made it an integer you can SUM them and check the total

```
SELECT *
FROM Friendship f1
JOIN Friendship f2
    ON f1.FID = f2.UID
    AND f1.UID = f2.FID
WHERE ((f1.IsActive = 1 AND f2.IsActive = 0)
OR (f1.IsActive = 0 AND f2.IsActive = 1))
```

And to get all active you can do the same but for a specific user and where both are active

```
SELECT *
FROM Friendship f1
JOIN Friendship f2
    ON f1.FID = f2.UID
    AND f1.UID = f2.FID
WHERE f1.IsActive = 1 
AND f2.IsActive = 1
AND f1.UID = 5
```

Comment: Oh lord. And I couldn't figure that out myself :(

Thank you very much. Hope this thread will help another SQL noob. Really appreciate it! Thanks msmucker0527.